# Shape parameterization of a polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to duplicate the below polynomial using numerical methods for optimization purposes. Based on some reading on the internet, there are many techniques, which are Bezier, B-spline, Parsec etc. I wonder what would be the easiest way to parametrize the polynomial below;

[image]

Comment: What about using linear regression to fit a polynomial to your data?

Comment: Do you want to keep the kink on the left ?

Comment: Yes. I want to duplicate it and I want to regenerate it using five points as follows;  (0.5 7.759), (0.3278, 13.72), (0.1947 28.93), (0.1321 40.49), (0.0695, 44.82). Thank you very much

Comment: Go for a cubic spline then. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html